# Number of Swappings/DataMovement in QuickSort Using Recursion

Tags: java

I can't seem to get how to find the number of dataMovements/Swappings in this code. Will there even be swappings/dataMovements in this Recursion Code ? 0_o and 
what would be it's memory space requirement ?

```
package skirmish;

    public class QuickSort 
    {
        public static int countComparisons = 0;
        public static int countSwappings = 0;
        public LinkedList qSort(LinkedList l)
        {
            if(l.count() <= 1)
                return l;

            int p = l.peekStart();
            l.removeFromStart();

            LinkedList s = new LinkedList();
            LinkedList g = new LinkedList();

            while(!l.isEmpty())
            {
                countComparisons++;
                if(l.peekStart() < p)
                    s.addAtEnd(l.peekStart());
                else
                    g.addAtEnd(l.peekStart());
                l.removeFromStart();
            }
            s = qSort(s);
            g = qSort(g);

            s.addAtEnd(p);
            countSwappings++;

            while(!g.isEmpty())
            {
                s.addAtEnd(g.peekStart());
                g.removeFromStart();
                countSwappings++;
            }

            return s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use letters as variable names. Also, I don't really understand what you want to count

Comment: Sorry for the naming convention. I want to count the number of swappings or data movements, like exchanges that we compare in any other sorting algorithm